# c# openxml : copy paragraph with font and alignment

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I want to copy a part of word *.docx to another *.docx file. For this I get a list of paragraphs from the original file :

```
private static List<Paragraph> getTextItems( string origFile )
{
    List<Paragraph> paragraphItems = new List<Paragraph>();
    var parser = new LineTextParser();

    using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open( origFile, false))
    {

        foreach (var el in doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements().OfType<Paragraph>())
        {
            if (parser.isHorizontalTableLine(el.InnerText))
            {
                if (true == el.InnerText.EndsWith("|"))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            paragraphItems.Add(el);
        }
    }

    return paragraphItems;
}
```

Then I'm trying to apply these items to a new file :

```
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
        WordprocessingDocument.Create(resultFile, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
        // Add a main document part. 
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

        // Create the document structure and add some text.
        mainPart.Document = new Document();
        Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
        foreach (var item in paragraphItems)
        {
            Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph() );
            para.Append(item.ParagraphProperties.CloneNode(true));
            Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
            run.AppendChild(new Text(item.InnerText));
        }
    }
```

But original formatting is lost - I mean the font has been changed and also alignment. What is the solution here?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Just edited my question and put the latest sources

Comment: You haven't provided any more info. I think we'd need to know the structure of the original doc and why the below code doesn't work for your doc.  Have you tried with a simpler test doc?

Comment: Yes, I tried with several docs - the issue comes when I change the style of the whole text in the original file. By default it's "Basic" - try to change it to smth else and run the script - you'll see that the output has "Basic" style, but not the one that was in the original file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of `item.InnerText` use `item.InnerXml` and set the new paragraph Xml to the source paragraph Xml.

You just need to re-order the way the paragraphs are being appended to the document.  The method below should create the file with the paragraphs copied from the original document.

```
public void CreateFile(string resultFile, List<Paragraph> paragraphItems)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
           WordprocessingDocument.Create(resultFile, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

        mainPart.Document = new Document();
        Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());

        foreach (var item in paragraphItems)
        {
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph();

            // set the inner Xml of the new paragraph
            para.InnerXml = item.InnerXml;

            // append paragraph to body here
            body.AppendChild(para);
        }
    }
}
```

Now we need to apply the styles from `doc.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart` to the new document.

This following method was modified from this MSDN [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-replace-the-styles-parts-in-a-word-processing-document).  It extracts the styles from `StyleDefinitionsPart` as an `XDocument`.

```
public XDocument ExtractStylesPart(string sourceFile)
{
    XDocument styles = null;

    // open readonly
    using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(sourceFile, false))
    {
        var docPart = document.MainDocumentPart;

        StylesPart stylesPart = docPart.StyleDefinitionsPart;

        if (stylesPart != null)
        {
            using (var reader = XmlNodeReader.Create(
                       stylesPart.GetStream(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
            {
                // Create the XDocument.
                styles = XDocument.Load(reader);
            }
        }
    }
    // Return the XDocument instance.
    return styles;
}
```

Then you need to save the style to the new document.  The following method should work for you:

```
public void SetStyleToTarget(string targetFile, XDocument newStyles)
{
    // open with write permissions
    using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(targetFile, true))
    {
            // add or get the style definition part
            StyleDefinitionsPart styleDefn = null;
            if (doc.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart == null)
            {
                styleDefn = doc.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<StyleDefinitionsPart>();
            }
            else
            {
                styleDefn = doc.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart;
            }

        // populate part with the new styles
        if (styleDefn != null)
        {
            // write the newStyle xDoc to the StyleDefinitionsPart using a streamwriter
            newStyles.Save(new StreamWriter(
                           styleDefn.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)));
        }
        // probably not needed (works for me with or without this save)
        doc.Save();
    }
}
```

The above method was inspired by the guide linked earlier.  The difference is that this creates a new style element for the new document (because it doesn't have one - we just created the doc).

I only used `StyleDefinitionsPart` but there is another part `StylesWithEffectsPart`.  You may need to implement similar method for the `StylesWithEffectsPart` if your document uses it.

Comment: Just tested your idea - I got XML inside docx :(.

Comment: @Dmitry I just realised it's appendng xml to the `Text()`.  Try `run.AppendChild(item.InnerXml);` - remove the `new Text()` element.

Comment: Got a compilation issue because AppendChild does not accept string

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot insert the OpenXmlElement "newChild" because it is part of a tree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190876/discussion-between-dmitry-and-haldo).

Comment: @Dmitry I found a solution that works for me, just needed to use `InnerXml` and re-order the way it's appended to the document.

Comment: Can you give me a snippet?

Comment: @Dmitry Found a solution that copies the style element and saves it to the new doc. Please see my updated answer

Comment: Just tested your solution - it works ! Thanks a lot for your help !